# React router not working on server, working fine on my localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

Hi have create React Based app it is working perfectly on my localhost but on in my server I am not getting why, I am using windows machine and I have host my webbsite on linux based AWS based server, issue is when I type any subpage link to browser addressbar then it dosen't open showing error cann't Get 'page path', it's fine on my localhost here my code

indexjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Webroute from './Webroute';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

    ReactDOM.render(( 
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Webroute /> 
        </BrowserRouter>
    ), 
    document.getElementById('root'));
    registerServiceWorker();
```

webroute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Components/Home/Home';
import Preview from './Components/Preview/Preview';
import Create from './Components/Create/Create';
import AllCards from './Components/AllCards/AllCards';
import Policy from './Components/Policy/policy';

const Webroute = () => (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/preview/:previewid/:type/:cardid" component={Preview} />
            <Route path="/create/:type/:cardid" component={Create} />
            <Route path="/browse" component={AllCards} />
            <Route path="/policy" component={Policy} />
            <Route path="*" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
)

export default Webroute;
```

Not getting idea what the wrong with it.. and why it's fine on my local machine.

Comment: Probably duplicated, but helps to find the correct answer! Thanks

Comment: did you found the solution?

Comment: @AvinashAjayPandey yep I got solution, It dosen't work on server because when we enter any url in browser then request goes first to server not in client side, I am using node on serverside so I need to accept get request on serverside then I render my clientside fom there then it works perfectly.

Comment: ok, thanks. can you add the answers here please in your file that would be a great help for me